# retrieving cookie value on page which has rewritten url

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cookies, url-rewriting, jquery-cookie

I am using `Jquery` cookie plugin. And I am also using `Url rewriting`

My question is how to retrieve cookie value on a page which has rewritten url and cookie is set on previous page where url is normal?

I wished this could work

```
$.cookie("cookieToRetrieve",{path:'../../../../'})
```

But unfortunately it's not working

Comment: If you set the path of the cookie as '/', it should be accessible from anywhere in the domain. URL rewriting should not impact it.

Comment: @GaneshKumar of course it's having an impact. I tested multiple times

Comment: Can you create jsFiddle or plunkr to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I do not thinks so. On one page app it will work. But to create such scenario takes at least more than one page

Comment: There is not much information in the post for someone to reproduce the issue. Can you post reproducible code.